# Receiving error after combining multiple arrays into one

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, object

I grouped a group of arrays under one array `$Final_updts[]` as follows :
Please note that the arrays were working fine before being combined.

```
array(5) { 
[0]=> array(0) { } 
[1]=> array(0) { } 
[2]=> array(3) { 
  [0]=> object(stdClass)#372 (21) { 
  ["id"]=> int(8) ["created_at"]=> string(19) "2019-11-08 11:07:55" 
  ["updated_at"]=> string(19) "2019-11-08 11:07:55" 
  ["title"]=> string(42) "question 1" ["body"]=> string(47) "Answer 1"}
}
```

I then returned it to the view :

```
return view('updates', ['f_updt' => $Final_updts]);
```

View :

```
@if(!empty($f_updt))
@foreach($f_updt as $f_updts)
<div class="post00" >
  <p>Other posts</p>
  <a href="/sharp/posts/{{ $f_updts->id }}"> 
    <h3> {{$f_updts->title}}  </h3>
    <br>
    <h5> {{$f_updts->body}}  </h5>
  </a>
</div>
<br>
@endforeach
@endif
```

I receive this error :

```
Trying to get property of non-object
```

Comment: Each of `$f_updts` variables is an array that could be empty. You should check the emptiness, and then if it is not empty, use  `$f_updts[0]->title` and `$f_updts[0]->body`

Comment: I don't want to use $f_updts[0] and then $f_updts[1]. I want only one array to be written once.

Answer (score 0):

```
@foreach($f_updt as $x => $f_updts)

   @foreach($f_updts as $f_updts1)
      @if(isset($f_updts1))
        @if(isset($f_updts1->id))

            <div class="post00">
                <p>Other posts</p>
                <a href="/sharp/posts/{{ $f_updts1->id }}">
                    <h3> {{$x}}  </h3>
                    <br>
                    <h4> {{$f_updts1->title}}  </h4>
                    <br>
                    <h5> {{$f_updts1->body}}  </h5>
                </a>
            </div>
            <br>
          @endif
        @endif
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```